# Trasnforming, kg ml, l, proportion into g proportion

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pd.Series

```
s = pd.Series(['3.95/kg', '3.30/kg', '3.49/kg', '3.96/g', '8.49/kg', '3.19/kg',
       '0.0154/g', '8.98/kg', '6.35/kg', '5.79/kg', '3.79/kg', '6.59/kg',
       '3.50/kg', '3.85/kg', '3.55/kg', '5.59/kg', '5.98/kg', '0.0152/g',
       '5.99/kg', '3.20/gr', '8.99/kg', '16.90/kg', '4.29/kg',
       '0.0128/g', '5.29/kg', '3.39/kg', '6.29/kg', '4.59/kg',
       '28.90/kg', '4.69/kg', '0.0389/gr', '0.0099/ml', '0.0608/g',])
```

What I want to do is to transform every single proportions into one single value for example, with it is in kg. Transform the proportion into grams, the same goess with ml and l proporitons.

So for example we got 3.95/kg on the string. I want the same proportion but in grams meaning we got to divide it by 1000 so it goes to 0.00395/g. If the string contains an ml well it remains the same. If it contains an l well it divides by 1000

Wanted result

```
pd.Series(['0.00395/g','0.00330/g','0,00349/g','3.96/g']) # And so on
```

Any ideas on how to do this treamtment utilizing pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
s = pd.Series(['3.95/kg', '3.30/kg', '3.49/kg', '3.96/g', '1.2/l', '0.0099/ml'])
```

`s`

```
0      3.95/kg
1      3.30/kg
2      3.49/kg
3       3.96/g
4        1.2/l
5    0.0099/ml
dtype: object
```

**Code**

```
df = s.str.split('/', expand=True)
```

`df`

```
    0       1
0   3.95    kg
1   3.30    kg
2   3.49    kg
3   3.96    g
4   1.2     l
5   0.0099  ml
```

make desired ouput by `df[0]` and `df[1]`

```
(df[0]
 .astype('float')
 .div(df[1].map({'kg':1000, 'g':1, 'l':1000, 'ml':1}))
 .astype('str')
 .str.cat(df[1].replace({'kg': 'g', 'l':'ml'}), sep='/'))
```

output:

```
0    0.00395/g
1     0.0033/g
2    0.00349/g
3       3.96/g
4    0.0012/ml
5    0.0099/ml
dtype: object
```